# customer lifetime value with mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have spent a week trying to figure this out, it is somewhat working by combining things from various sources but not fully working yet.

Basically I have an *orders* table which I'm trying to group customers by their first order date, then show the total spent by this group up to now.

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email, billing_name,
FORMAT(SUM(total),2) AS total,
DATE_FORMAT(MIN(orderdate), '%Y-%m') AS firstorder,
DATE_FORMAT(MAX(orderdate), '%Y-%m') AS lastorder
FROM orders
GROUP BY email
ORDER BY firstorder ASC
```

and with PHP I am doing:

```
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
$rows[] = $row;
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $currMonth = $row['firstorder'];
    $total += $row['total'];
    if ($currMonth != $prevMonth) {
            echo $currMonth.' = $'.$total';
            $prevMonth = $currMonth;
            $total = 0;
        }
    }
```

this gives me a list like:

```
    2010-05 = $230.49
    2010-06 = $557.32
    2010-08 = $223.38
```

but the numbers don't add up, what am i doing wrong? and how can I display how much a group have spent in other months? this is how I eventually want to show the data, http://www.quickcohort.com/

Please help! thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're really after and what your data looks like.

If data looks like:

```
email          |BILLING NAME|Total  |OrderDate
----------------------------------------------
john@gmail.com |John Smith  |200.00 |15/05/2010
john@gmail.com |John Smith  | 15.49 |19/10/2010
john@gmail.com |Rico Swavez | 15.00 |10/08/2010
jane@gmail.com |Jane Doe    |250.00 |23/06/2010
jane@gmail.com |Jane Doe    |307.32 |27/10/2010
juan@gmail.com |Juan Valdez |223.38 |30/08/2010
```

Then...

```
SELECT email, billing_name,
FORMAT(SUM(total),2) AS total,
DATE_FORMAT(MIN(orderdate), '%Y-%m') AS firstorder,
DATE_FORMAT(MAX(orderdate), '%Y-%m') AS lastorder
FROM orders
GROUP BY email, billing_name
ORDER BY firstorder ASC
```

Will return

```
EMAIL          | BILLING NAME |TOTAL |FIRSTORDER | LASTORDER 
------------------------------------------------------------
john@gmail.com | John Smith   |215.49|2010-05    | 2010-10
jane@gmail.com | Jane Doe     |557.32|2010-06    | 2010-10
john@gmail.com | Rico Swavez  | 15.00|2010-08    | 2010-08
Juan@gmail.com | Juan Valdez  |223.38|2010-08    | 2010-08
```

Run your query first in mysql are you getting the results you want? if not, then the problem is in the SQL, not the PHP.  If the SQL is returning what you want, then the problem is in the PHP

Comment: hey man, thanks for looking in to this. yes i forgot to mention that i could not solve the problem in sql so i was trying to solve this in php. yes i would like to do a group by on firstorder.

here is what i really wanted to do with with the sql:
group customers by their first order date and see what each group spent over the other months.

Comment: Ok let's talk about what your desired output is then, because I don't get it yet.  You want to display total purchases for a user based on month/year and only render the first month's totals? (yes/no)  Or are you trying to render all of an email totals for all purchases but just show the first date of purchase?  I'm not sure what you're after yet.  Sample out put with sample inputs go a long way to helping explain a problem:  Input --> process --> output..  If I know Input, and I know output, I can derive process (sometimes).

Comment: i want to group customers on their first order date and see how much the group spent over the months and add up the totals
please see this site, http://www.quickcohort.com/ for my desired output. i would like to show the graph with totals on each month.

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do the trick:

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(SUM(z.`totalSpent`),2) AS cohortRevenueToDate, 
    z.`firstOrderMonth`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`email`) 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        `email`,
        SUM(`total`) AS totalSpent, 
        DATE_FORMAT(MIN(`orderdate`), '%Y-%m') AS firstOrderMonth 
    FROM `orders`
    GROUP BY `email`
) AS z
GROUP BY z.`firstOrderMonth`
ORDER BY z.`firstOrderMonth` ASC
```

I have included a GROUP_CONCAT in case you are interested on each cohort composition.